# What is correct? "Helps me get ready" or "Helps me getting ready"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

"Helps me get ready" or "Helps me getting ready"

I just had this discussion recently, and online resources have been unable to provide the answer. I am aware that it is possible that neither is correct, so in that case, how do you say it?

Comment: There's an (implied) *to* after *Helps me* - does that help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Helps me (to) get ready' or 'helps me **in** getting ready'. You can use 'help' with the base (infinitive) part of a verb to say that something helps you (to) do the thing expressed by the verb, or with 'in' and the gerund (-ing) form of the verb.

> help
>   verb
>   [..]
>   **help (somebody) in doing something**
>   I need contacts that could help in finding a job.
>
> **help somebody (to) do something**
>   *The college’s aim is to help students (to) achieve their
>   aspirations.
>
>   This charity aims to help people (to) help themselves.
>
>   Come and help me lift this box.*
>   [..]

[Help (verb)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/help_1)